# Character Encoding in LINUX for java

Tags: linux, encoding, character

We had to recompile an existing java code today to change the directory path hardcoded on the original code
java was recompiled with the following command line command in LINUX

> javac -verbose -classpath
>   /data/flexapp/maxmind/api/GeoIPJava-1.2.8/source:.
>   CityLookupTest2.java

We saw differences in the outputs produced using the new compiled code vs the old one and the byte difference seem to be ont he double-byte or international characters. See the bolded code below

```
[flexapp@gaalplpclu02df pp]$ cat currtrackgeo.201301031445.run1|grep 1ZY9307E6894015571
01/03/2013 14:46:43.004,TrackHTML,1ZY9307E6894015571,,92.56.217.169,en_US,,ES,51,VÃ©lez-mÃ¡laga,null,36.7726,-4.100403,0,0

[flexapp@gaalplpclu02df pp]$ cat currtrackgeo.201301031445|grep 1ZY9307E6894015571
01/03/2013 14:46:43.004,TrackHTML,1ZY9307E6894015571,,92.56.217.169,en_US,,ES,51,V?lez-m?laga,null,36.7726,-4.100403,0,0
```

I tried to use the following encoding parms but it all resulted to the same output

```
-encoding ISO-8859-1
-encoding ISO-8859-2
-encoding UTF-8
```

The original programmer left already and there is no documentation on how the old code was compiled before. Do you think this is an encoding parm that was applied to replace all double-byte characters to ? from Ã in this example.

Hope you can assist since I do not want to confuse my user community with the new variation on the column

Comment: where did you get the double-byte text? were they written in your java source code or stored in other source (textfile/properties/database....) ?

Comment: Hi Kent.. the web service we have allows for them since they are city names in the local character for International..

Comment: Location l1 = cl.getLocation(ip);
                if(ip.length() > 0 && l1 != null ) {
            System.out.println(s1 + "," + l1.countryCode +
                                "," +  l1.region +
                                "," + l1.city +
                                "," + l1.postalCode +
                                "," + l1.latitude +
                                "," + l1.longitude +
                                          "," + l1.metro_code +
                                  "," + l1.area_code );
                }

Comment: @E B , -encoding defines the character encoding used by your source code. e.g. if you hardcoded some double-bytes words in your source codes, you should give the corresponding -encoding when you compile it. in your case, I would check two parts, A, retrieving the value from WS. If it is with right encoding. B, when writing to file (csv perhaps) if with right encoding.

Comment: i specified the encoding during the compile? I specified ISO-8859-1 on one compile, ISO-8859-2 on the other and UTF-8 on the other. All of them produced the same letters instead of ? which the old program was doing.. The input file used by the WebService is not a text file so I guess I can only do a println to see the output before I write. Can I country the way it is written in csv?